# Captcha trouble with xampp

Tags: php, wordpress, xampp, captcha

I am developing my WordPress website locally using XAMPP server, but Contact Form 7 Captcha functionality does not work. That is, clicking on the Submit button, a spinning arrow appears and the form does not do any thing.

```
<p>Nom (required)<br />
    [text* your-name] </p>

<p>Email (required)<br />
    [email* your-email] </p>

<p>Telephone (required)<br />
   [text phonenumber]</p>

<p>Sujet<br />
    [text your-subject] </p>

<p>Message<br />
    [textarea your-message] </p>

<p>Remplir le code : [captchac captcha-914 bg:#01DF01 size:m]<br />
[captchar captcha-914]
     </p>

<p>[submit "Send"]</p>
```

Comment: Can you post the code you use to include the `Contact Form 7 Captcha`? Do you get any JavaScript errors on the page (check your browsers console to see any JavaScript errors)?

Comment: it works normally without captcha

Comment: Nom (required)
[text* your-name]

Email (required)
[email* your-email]

Telephone (required)
[text phonenumber]

Sujet
[text your-subject]

Message
[textarea your-message]

Remplir le code : [captchac captcha-914 bg:#01DF01 size:m]
[captchar captcha-914]

[submit "Send"]

Comment: which wordpress version did you use ?